# How can I SELECT values from another table in a new column instead of adding rows

Tags: sql

Table 1:

| EMPLID | CHKDate | GrossPay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2023-1-1 | 2000.00 |

Table 2:

| EMPLID | CHKDate | EarningCode | Earnings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2023-1-1 | Regular | 500.00 |
| 12345 | 2023-1-1 | PTO | 500.00 |
| 12345 | 2023-1-1 | Bonus | 1000.00 |

I'm trying to add the earnings as new columns instead of joining which will make it three rows:

| EMPLID | CHKDate | GrossPay | Regular | PTO | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2023-1-1 | 2000.00 | 500.00 | 500.00 | 1000.00 |

Join is the only thing I've been able to do but it results in three rows:

```
SELECT 
    Table1.EMPLID, Table1.CHKDate, Table1.GrossPay, 
    Table2.EarningCode, Table2.Earnings
FROM
    Table1
JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table1.EMPLID = Table2.EMPLID 
           AND Table1.CHKDate = Table2.CHKDate
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You still want to join, but you also want to pivot and sum.  Pivot syntax can vary by RDBMS.  you could also issue correlated inline select queries but I find those ugly to maintain

Answer (score 0):

You still want to join you just need to aggregrate the results and use case expression to limit what data is placed where.  The case expressions effectively do a manual pivot.

Example of a manual pivot using case expressions which is usually DB agnostic as Pivot implementations are often DB Specific.

It does assume that EmployeeID, checkdate and gross pay will only have 1 record each and if more than 1 exists, you want the pay, and totals summed: for [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/pJJl7vmS)

Tested: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TLcVjcGu)

```
SELECT 
    Table1.EMPLID, Table1.CHKDate, Table1.GrossPay
  , sum(case when Table2.EarningsCode = 'Regular' then Table2.Earnings else 0 end) as Regular
  , sum(case when Table2.EarningsCode = 'PTO' then Table2.Earnings else 0 end) as PTO
  , sum(case when Table2.EarningsCode = 'Bonus' then Table2.Earnings else 0 end) as Bonus
FROM
    Table1
JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table1.EMPLID = Table2.EMPLID 
           AND Table1.CHKDate = Table2.CHKDate
GROUP BY    Table1.EMPLID, Table1.CHKDate, Table1.GrossPay;
```